# Grails validate delete() Operation?

Tags: spring-mvc, grails, groovy, grails-orm, grails-2.0

When deleting an instance with Grails I can perform

```
def user = User.get(1)
user.delete(flush: true)
```

For an instance I can validate if a save operation will succeed:

```
user.validate()
```

**Is it possible to validate if a delete() will be successful before doing delete?**

Comment: If you're deleting an instance why you need to validate it?

Comment: I guess the intention was to check if any foreign key constraint is violated upon delete. Only way I think is mentioned in answer, to check for any exception.

Comment: Please note that [Grails validation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#validation) is just a way to perform *your* business validation logic. This is *not* a "dry run" for the save() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to 'dry run' a delete in Grails. You could do something like this though:

```
try{
   user.delete(failOnError:true)
} 
catch(e) {
   //it didn't work, do something about it here
}
```